# Can I programmatically attach a running .NET 6 process to a running instance of Visual Studio debugger?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, debugging, .net-6.0

I'm debugging an IPC logic where one .NET 6 processes is launching another, and I can't get to debug both within the same Visual Studio 2022 instance.

When the child process hits `DebugBreak(true)` as below:

```cs
    [Conditional("ATTACH_DEBUGGER")]
    public static void DebugBreak(bool condition)
    {
        if (condition)
        {
            if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
                System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            }
        }
    }
```

I get prompted to launch a new instance of VS2022 to debug it:

[image: VS 2022 attach debugger]

However, I want to debug it within the existing VS instance, were I'm already debugging the parent process.

**Is that possible at all? Is there a VS config setting I might be missing?**

Current workaround: attaching manually, while putting the child process in the waiting state using `WaitForDebugger()` below:

```cs
    [Conditional("ATTACH_DEBUGGER")]
    public static void WaitForDebugger()
    {
        using var process = Process.GetCurrentProcess();
        Console.WriteLine($"Waiting for debugger, process: {process.ProcessName}, id: {process.Id}, Assembly: {Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location}");

        while (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
        {
            // hit Esc to continue without debugger
            if (Console.KeyAvailable && Console.ReadKey(intercept: true).KeyChar == 27)
            {
                break;
            }
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            Console.Beep(frequency: 1000, duration: 50);
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you need two instances of VS running to debug two different `.exe` processes

Comment: @Charlieface, I can manually attach multiple processes to the same VS debugger instance. That works, confirmed (see "Current workaround" in my question). It's just somewhat annoying, as I need to lookup the child process in the list of all running processes (Ctrl+Alt+P dialog in VS).

Comment: IIRC, previously the current VS instance was showing up in the "Choose Just-in-Time Debugger" dialog (on the pic). This is no longer the case, at least for VS2022 and .NET 6.

Comment: I've managed to get this working for Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Core 5 and have updated my answer with a working code sample. Changes for VS2022 and .NET Core 6 should be minimal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a very similar setup where the following steps achieve this. However, this is with **.NET Framework** so I cannot guarantee it will work with .NET Core. **(UPDATE: see below for .NET Core approach;** see end for link to complete code samples on GitHub.)

First, identify a point in your *first* process (say, `FirstProcess`) where you want to attach the debugger to the *second* process (`SecondProcess`). Obviously `SecondProcess` will need to be running by this point (as `SecondProcess.exe`, say).

Open Solution Explorer and navigate to `References` for the relevant project in `FirstProcess`. Right-click, search for "env" and add two references, `EnvDTE (v.8.0.0.0)` and `EnvDTE80 (v.8.0.0.0)`.

Add the following methods to the class in `FirstProcess` from where you want to attach:

```
private static void Attach(DTE2 dte)
{
    var processName = "SecondProcess.exe";
    var processes = dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses;
    
    // Note: Depending on your setup, consider whether an exact match is required instead of using .IndexOf()
    foreach (var proc in processes.Cast<EnvDTE.Process>().Where(proc => proc.Name.IndexOf(processName) != -1))
    {
        proc.Attach();
    }
}

private static DTE2 GetCurrent()
{
    // Note: "16.0" is for Visual Studio 2019; you might need to tweak this for VS2022.
    var dte2 = (DTE2)Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.16.0");
    return dte2;
}
```

Visual Studio should now prompt you to add the following references to your class:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using EnvDTE80;
```

Finally, insert the following line at the point in `FirstProcess` where you wish to attach the debugger to `SecondProcess`:

```
Attach(GetCurrent());
```

If you manage to get this working, please feel free to edit this answer with any changes needed for the .NET Core environment.

**UPDATE - for .NET Core:**

For .NET Core there are two problems to overcome:

1. The DTE references are not available in .NET Core. However, they can
   be added as NuGet packages. **You will need to add two NuGet
   packages,** `envdte` and `envdte80` (both by Microsoft with 2M+
   downloads), to `FirstProcess`.
2. The method `Marshal.GetActiveObject()` is not available in .NET
   Core. To resolve this you can get the source code from Microsoft
   ([here](https://github.com/microsoft/referencesource/blob/5697c29004a34d80acdaf5742d7e699022c64ecd/mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs#L2404)) and add it manually; **this has already been done in
   the code sample below**.

**What follows is a complete working .NET Core code sample for `FirstProcess`.** This correctly attaches programmatically to `SecondProcess` after startup.

```cs
namespace FirstProcess
{
    using System;
    using System.Diagnostics;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Runtime.Versioning;
    using System.Security;
    using System.Threading;

    using EnvDTE80;

    class Program
    {
        private const string FileName = "C:\\Users\\YourUserName\\source\\repos\\TwoProcessesSolution\\SecondProcess\\bin\\Debug\\net5.0\\SecondProcess.exe";
        private const string ProcessName = "SecondProcess";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var childProcess = Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(FileName));
            
            Attach(GetCurrent());

            while (true)
            {
                // Your code here.
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
            }

            childProcess.Kill();
        }

        private static void Attach(DTE2 dte)
        {
            var processes = dte.Debugger.LocalProcesses;

            // Note: Depending on your setup, consider whether an exact match is required instead of using .IndexOf()
            foreach (var proc in processes.Cast<EnvDTE.Process>().Where(proc => proc.Name.IndexOf(ProcessName) != -1))
            {
                proc.Attach();
            }
        }

        private static DTE2 GetCurrent()
        {
            // Note: "16.0" is for Visual Studio 2019; you might need to tweak this for VS2022.
            var dte2 = (DTE2)Marshal2.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE.16.0");
            
            return dte2;
        }

        public static class Marshal2
        {
            internal const String OLEAUT32 = "oleaut32.dll";
            internal const String OLE32 = "ole32.dll";

            [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated_required
            public static Object GetActiveObject(String progID)
            {
                Object obj = null;
                Guid clsid;

                // Call CLSIDFromProgIDEx first then fall back on CLSIDFromProgID if
                // CLSIDFromProgIDEx doesn't exist.
                try
                {
                    CLSIDFromProgIDEx(progID, out clsid);
                }
                    //            catch
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    CLSIDFromProgID(progID, out clsid);
                }

                GetActiveObject(ref clsid, IntPtr.Zero, out obj);
                return obj;
            }

            //[DllImport(Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.OLE32, PreserveSig = false)]
            [DllImport(OLE32, PreserveSig = false)]
            [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
            [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
            [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
            private static extern void CLSIDFromProgIDEx([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String progId, out Guid clsid);

            //[DllImport(Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.OLE32, PreserveSig = false)]
            [DllImport(OLE32, PreserveSig = false)]
            [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
            [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
            [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
            private static extern void CLSIDFromProgID([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPWStr)] String progId, out Guid clsid);

            //[DllImport(Microsoft.Win32.Win32Native.OLEAUT32, PreserveSig = false)]
            [DllImport(OLEAUT32, PreserveSig = false)]
            [ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
            [SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
            [System.Security.SecurityCritical]  // auto-generated
            private static extern void GetActiveObject(ref Guid rclsid, IntPtr reserved, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Interface)] out Object ppunk);

        }
    }
}
```

Note 1: This is for **Visual Studio 2019 and .NET Core 5**. I would expect this to work for VS2022 and .NET Core 6 with a single change to the Visual Studio version as annotated above.

Note 2: You will need to have **only one instance of Visual Studio open** (though if this isn't possible, the code is probably fixable quite easily).

**Downloadable demo**

Complete working examples for both .NET Framework (v4.7.2) and .NET Core (v5.0) are available on GitHub here: https://github.com/NeilTalbott/VisualStudioAutoAttacher

Comment: Very cool. Could you make a demo project available in a GitHub repo maybe? That could help lots of people. I'll let this question hang for a little longer for exposure, before rewarding your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks - and that's a good idea. I'll look into doing that if I have some time at the weekend.

Comment: I found some time over lunch. GitHub link now added to the end of the answer.