# Unable to debug project within solution when it is not the startup project

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, dll, pdb-files

I have an application that has a startup project (ProjectA) that runs another executable in another Project (ProjectB).  When I start the solution with ProjectA as the startup project, I am unable to debug ProjectB.  It is unable to load the PDB file even though it is in the directory where its searching.

However, when I start the application and ProjectB is the startup project, I am able to debug it.  I assume this is because it is referencing the executable instead of the dll.

Why is this so?  How do I get around this so that I can have ProjectA be the startup project and still debug ProjectB?

Comment: The following may (or may not) be helpful: [How to: Set multiple startup projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-set-multiple-startup-projects?view=vs-2022)

Comment: Honestly, probably not really the way to do it.  Unless you actually need to be able to run projectB directly of course.  ProjectB should probably be a class library referenced in ProjectA.  Maybe update your question with a little more detail (code examples) about how exactly the two projects interact.

Comment: How does ProjectA run ProjectB?  How are you trying to debug ProjectB?

Comment: I would expect that you would need a separate debugger session to attach to the second executable, since I would expect it to be running as a separate process.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, your Project A has started the Project B `.exe`. Something along these lines:

```
Public Class ProjectAForm
    Private Sub ButtonRunProjectB_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles ButtonRunProjectB.Click
        Process.Start("D:\Github\stackoverflow\multi-project-debugging\project-b\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\project-b.exe")
    End Sub
End Class
```

You want to debug Project B in this context, but your debugger is attached only to Project A and not to Project B:

[image: not attached]

---

**Manual**

The interactive way to go about it is with DEBUG\Attach to Process...

[image: attach to process]

Now you will hit your breakpoints.

[image: attached]

---

**Programmatic**

Doing this automatically is tricky but possible. Refer to this answer:

[Can I programmatically attach a running .NET 6 process to a running instance of Visual Studio debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72075450/5438626)

---

**Suggestion**

If Project A *doesn't* reference Project B directly (that is, they're completely independent inside a common solution where Project A is the startup) I find that it saves a lot of confusion to have Project B build automatically (if needed) whenever Project A runs. Manually setting `project-a` to depend on `project-b` achieves this outcome.

[image: project dependencies]